# Set BackGround Color of Textbox to Transparent

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to set the background color of textbox to transparent, to blend with my backcolor of my form.

I have tried the following below.

```
 TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent 'This doesn't work it stays white'
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Im not switching just to change back color :)

Comment: If your form is a solid color, just set the TextBox BackColor to that same color instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I set `TextBox.BackColor` to `Color.Transparent`, it throws `System.ArgumentException`. I got this message :

`Unvalid property value, The control does not support transparent colors background`.

Comment: even `TextBox1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(1, Color.Gray)` throws the same error, when you switch the fist parameter to define degree of transparency http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hstcth9(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hope am not late to the party, but this actually works for me. First create a class for the panel as below

```
Partial Public Class iPanel
    Inherits Panel
    Public Sub New()
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor Or ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer Or ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw Or ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
        BackColor = Color.Transparent
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then create a `RichTextBox` (Instead of a `Textbox`) as below

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
         Dim CP As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
         CP.ExStyle = CP.ExStyle Or &H20
         Return CP
    End Get
End Property
```

Now compile the code and add the iRichTextBox inside the panel. Works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Paint
    TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.White
    TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
End Sub
```

Instead of doing the first one, You can try this. Just put your code in Form Load

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    TextBox1.BackColor = color.(color of your Choice, same color of your background)
    TextBox1.ForeColor = color.White

End Sub
```

As simple as that, it works for me

Comment: Color.White isn't Color.Transparent

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know textbox `does not support` transparent color property. **But** if you set the `back color` of the `textbox` to the `same` color as of its `background component`, still it can be considered as `transparent`.

**How to do that** - You can get the color name of the background component(in your case it is the form) and pass that name to the component which you want to be transparent.

```
Dim lname As String = Me.BackColor.ToString
Dim name As String = lname.Substring(7, lname.Length - 8)
txtbox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(name)
```

**Explanation** -

1. The first line in the code gets you the name of the color, but there's a rub, it gets the name something like this - `Color [Dark Orange]` and we need only the name of the color i.e `Dark Orange`.
2. Thus the second line is to get the exact color name by removing this - `Color []` part
3. And the last line to set that color same as of the background component color.
   Hope it works, still have problem let me know...

Comment: Wouldn't it be much more simple to do txtbox1.BackColor=Me.BackColor ?